# Complex conjugate of real number

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I'm trying to take complex conjugate of some terms in a function. I tried this

```
α = αr + I*αi;
β = βr + I*βi;
$Assumptions = Element[αr, Reals];
$Assumptions = Element[αi, Reals];
$Assumptions = Element[βr, Reals];
$Assumptions = Element[βi, Reals];

b0 = (T0*(β - R1*Exp[2*I*(w*l/c)]*α)/((R0*beta - Conjugate[α]) - 
       R1*Exp[2*I*(w*l/c)]*(R0*α - Conjugate[β])))*fw
```

but the output I get is

```
(fw T0 (-E^(((2 I l w)/c)) R1 (I αi + αr) + I βi + βr))/(
  beta R0 + I Conjugate[αi] - Conjugate[αr] - 
    E^((2 I l w)/c) R1 (R0 (I αi + αr) + I Conjugate[βi] - Conjugate[βr]))
```

I don't understand what to do to get rid of the terms containing `Conjugate`, e.g. `Conjugate[αi]` etc.

Comment: Use `$Assumptions = Element[{αr, αi, βr, βi}, Reals]` and then don't forget to `FullSimplify` your expression `b0` in order to apply these assumptions.

Comment: `$Assumptions` only affects functions that have the `Assumptions` option. `Conjugate` is not one of these, but e.g. `Simplify` is, which you can apply to your expression. Also look up `ComplexExpand`.

Comment: `ComplexExpand` might also be worth a read.